# How do I find the password for my "Local Items" keychain?

Tags: security, password, keychain, macos

I'm looking through passwords in Keychain Access, but some of them are prompting me for a password for a keychain I'm not familiar with.  How do I find the password for my "Local Items" keychain?

My login password is not working.  Since there are other questions about this keychain (none of which pertain to my question), I obviously didn't create it.  I don't recall ever setting any password for it.

[image: dialog box asking for a password to the "Local Items" keychain]